# Mysql run a script in many database

Tags: mysql, database

I have an application with many identical databases. I need to create an sql update script to alter all these databases.

There is a databases index table with all databases stored in the Mysql istance:

```
create table db (dbname varchar(64), active tinyint);
insert into db values ('db1',1),('db2',1),('db3',1);
```

I need to run an alter script for each database in that list. So i need something like a foreach of previus select and run a "use db" before the alter command.

Something like this but in sql:

```
foreach(db in "select dbname from db"){
   use db;
   alter table1 ....;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create another database to hold other database records. Database name, username, passwords, IPs etc. And then you can query from that database and use a foreach loop.

Comment: I just need to loop for each row and run a script... is it not possibile in mysql?